# How do you sort dates in a dictionary?

Tags: swift

I am having trouble trying to sort the following dictionary, so that it is printed in oldest date first order when printed.

```
var dayTotalDicTest: [String:Int] =

            [
                "04-09-2015" : 4,
                "04-10-2015" : 6,
                "04-07-2015" : 8,
                "03-28-2015" : 10,
                "12-10-2014" : 12,
                "12-10-2015" : 12,

            ]
```

Comment: In most languages, you can't sort the keys in a dictionary. That's not the point of a dictionary. A dictionary is for constant time insert and retrieval. And for keys that aren't integers. If you put the key value pairs into a list, you can sort that.

Comment: dayTotalArrayTest is not an array it is a dictionary. You can't actually sort a dictionary

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**edit/update: Xcode 8.2.1 • Swift 3.0.2**

```
extension String {
    static let shortDateUS: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateStyle = .short
        return formatter
    }()
    var shortDateUS: Date? {
        return String.shortDateUS.date(from: self)
    }
}

let dayTotalDicTest: [String:Int] = [
    "04-09-2015" : 4,
    "04-10-2015" : 6,
    "04-07-2015" : 8,
    "03-28-2015" : 10,
    "12-10-2014" : 12,
    "12-10-2015" : 12]

let myArrayOfTuples = dayTotalDicTest.sorted{
    guard let d1 = $0.key.shortDateUS, let d2 = $1.key.shortDateUS else { return false }
    return d1 < d2
}

print(myArrayOfTuples)  // [("12-10-2014", 12), ("03-28-2015", 10), ("04-07-2015", 8), ("04-09-2015", 4), ("04-10-2015", 6), ("12-10-2015", 12)]\n"

for tuple in myArrayOfTuples {
    print(tuple)
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed, thank you! Also fixed my wording issues in the question, thanks again.

Comment: Indeed, you should batch-convert your date strings to Dates, then sort by date.

Comment: @DuncanC Such an old question. My answer would be totally different from that. Would you like me to update it?

Comment: I just added an updated answer that builds an array containing Dates, sorts them, and then strips off the dates.

Comment: @DuncanC  You should use .key instead of .0 and .value instead of .1 in Swift 3 readability wise speaking.

Comment: Good point, but shouldn't you comment on my answer, not yours? :) (Moot point - I edited my answer based on your suggestion.)

Answer (score 6):

In Swift 3 Date objects are now comparable, we can accomplish what you want as follows:

```
let dayTotalDicTest: [String:Int] = [
  "04-09-2015" : 4,
  "04-10-2015" : 6,
  "04-07-2015" : 8,
  "03-28-2015" : 10,
  "12-10-2014" : 12,
  "12-10-2015" : 12]

//Create a date formatter to convert our date strings to Date objects
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"

let sortedArrayOfDicts = dayTotalDicTest
  //First map to an array tuples: [(Date, [String:Int]]
  .map{(df.date(from: $0.key)!, [$0.key:$0.value])}

  //Now sort by the dates, using `<` since dates are Comparable.
  .sorted{$0.0 < $1.0}

  //And re-map to discard the Date objects
  .map{$1}

for item in sortedArrayOfDicts {
  print(item)
}
```

The code above does a one-time mapping of the key/value pairs to tuples where the first element is a Date object, and the second entry in the tuple is a single-element dictionary containing the oringinal key/value pair. It then sorts the array of tuples, and then maps the sorted array to extract the key/value pairs, so what you're left with is an array of single-element dictionaries from the original data structure.

When you sort, you want to avoid expensive operations during the comparison operations of the sort. Converting date strings to dates is fairly slow. Doing that conversion during each comparison in the sort is extra inefficient, because you end up comparing each element in your array to multiple other elements, so you do the string-to-date conversions over and over.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries cannot be sorted, so you have to convert it to an array. Either `map` or `sorted` can do that for you. Also, the strings cannot be sorted as provided, so you either need to restructure the string into `yyyy-MM-dd` format, or convert it to a date.

But once you've done that, you can then sort the array. For example, using functional programming in Swift, you could do something like the following, which uses `sorted` to convert the dictionary to an array and then sort using the closure and then using `DateFormatter` to convert the strings to dates:

```
let dictionary = [
    "04-09-2015": 4,
    "04-10-2015": 6,
    "04-07-2015": 8,
    "03-28-2015": 10,
    "12-10-2014": 12,    
    "12-10-2015": 12
]

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"

let result = dictionary.sorted {
    formatter.date(from: $0.0)! < formatter.date(from: $1.0)! 
}
```

While that enjoys a certain simplicity, it's probably a tad inefficient, calling `date(from:)` more than we need to. So, I'd probably have the `map` function add the `Date` object to the array of tuples, and then `sorted` can use that:

```
let result = dictionary.map { (formatter.date(from: $0)!, $0, $1) }
    .sorted { $0.0 < $1.0 }
    .map { ($0.1, $0.2) }
```

That final `map` discards the `Date` object, but clearly you don't need to do that if you're ok keeping the `Date` in the tuple.

Comment: That code certainly works, but string to date conversion is quite slow. Doing that inside the sorted method's comparison closure makes it extra-slow. Better to map the dates dictionary to an array that contains Date objects before sorting, then sort. See my answer.

Comment: @DuncanC - Lol. That’s the whole point of the second half of my answer. So, I first show the reader what’s going on conceptually (using formatters to convert strings to dates and sorting on the basis of that) and I then show the reader how to do that efficiently (doing the conversion once, up front). In fact, your answer just looks like it is largely just a Swift 3 conversion of my original Swift 1.2 answer, posted years earlier. Regardless, I’ve updated my answer to the current Swift version.

Comment: I guess I missed the second part of your answer. That is short and elegant. (Voted). Please don’t accuse me of plagiarism though. I am careful to credit other’s work if I use it in my own.

Comment: I didn’t mean to suggest willful plagiarism. I’ve seen enough of your posts to know that this is not how you roll. I was just pointing out the similarity of your answer and the final recommendation of mine… 

Answer (score -1):

Your dates are strings, so they are being sorted according to `string` sorting rules. Change the format to `yyyy-MM-dd` and they should sort correctly.

This assumes, mind you, that you can rearrange key value pairs in a dictionary in the first place.