# Swift how to "sort" a dictionary from JSON to plot it in a time series?

Tags: json, swift, sorting, dictionary

**Yes I know there's no point in sorting a dictionary and a dictionary is unsorted by definition.**

However I need the key (in date) to be sorted so I can use it to plot it in a plot (much like the last 30 day price plot in stocks)

I currently have tried the 2 methods found in here: [How do you sort dates in a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552292/how-do-you-sort-dates-in-a-dictionary)

however, they didnt work for me.

Can anyone tell me what I should do in this case so I can get the x-axis in my plot to plot the dates in order (instead of "2018-01-12" "2017-12-30" "2018-1-20")?

here's my code

```
func pastThirtyDaysData(money: String) {    
   Alamofire.request("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json?currency=\(money)").responseJSON{ (dataFromAPI) in
      if dataFromAPI.result.value != nil {
         let myJSON = JSON(dataFromAPI.result.value)["bpi"].dictionaryObject
         print(myJSON!)
      }
   }
}
```

I am not sure what I should do here to sort my dictionary key by date so that I can use that data to plot it in my plot

Thank you for your helps and thoughts

Here's the JSON  output:

```
{
  "bpi": {
"2017-12-21": 15561.05,
"2017-12-22": 13857.145,
"2017-12-23": 14548.71,
"2017-12-24": 13975.4363,
"2017-12-25": 13917.0275,
"2017-12-26": 15745.2575,
"2017-12-27": 15378.285,
"2017-12-28": 14428.76,
"2017-12-29": 14427.87,
"2017-12-30": 12629.8138,
"2017-12-31": 13860.1363,
"2018-01-01": 13412.44,
"2018-01-02": 14740.7563,
"2018-01-03": 15134.6513,
"2018-01-04": 15155.2263,
"2018-01-05": 16937.1738,
"2018-01-06": 17135.8363,
"2018-01-07": 16178.495,
"2018-01-08": 14970.3575,
"2018-01-09": 14439.4738,
"2018-01-10": 14890.7225,
"2018-01-11": 13287.26,
"2018-01-12": 13812.715,
"2018-01-13": 14188.785,
"2018-01-14": 13619.0288,
"2018-01-15": 13585.9013,
"2018-01-16": 11348.02,
"2018-01-17": 11141.2488,
"2018-01-18": 11250.6475,
"2018-01-19": 11514.925,
"2018-01-20": 12759.6413
  },
  "disclaimer": "This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index. BPI value data returned as USD.",
  "time": {
"updated": "Jan 21, 2018 00:03:00 UTC",
"updatedISO": "2018-01-21T00:03:00+00:00"
  }
}
```

This is my console output:

```
["2018-01-19": 11514.925, "2018-01-13": 14188.785, "2017-12-22": 13857.145, "2018-01-02": 14740.7563, "2017-12-29": 14427.87, "2018-01-10": 14890.7225, "2017-12-21": 15561.05, "2018-01-16": 11348.02, "2018-01-17": 11141.2488, "2018-01-03": 15134.6513, "2018-01-15": 13585.9013, "2017-12-31": 13860.1363, "2017-12-30": 12629.8138, "2017-12-27": 15378.285, "2018-01-12": 13812.715, "2017-12-23": 14548.71, "2018-01-05": 16937.1738, "2018-01-18": 11250.6475, "2017-12-25": 13917.0275, "2017-12-28": 14428.76, "2018-01-04": 15155.2263, "2018-01-11": 13287.26, "2018-01-08": 14970.3575, "2018-01-14": 13619.0288, "2017-12-24": 13975.4363, "2018-01-20": 12759.6413, "2018-01-06": 17135.8363, "2018-01-09": 14439.4738, "2018-01-01": 13412.44, "2018-01-07": 16178.495, "2017-12-26": 15745.2575]
```

Comment: may you post such JSON response?

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini sorry forgot to post it. Thank you for the reminder

Comment: Maybe you can put all the keys from the dictionary into an array using dict.keys and sort the dates. Then you can access your data like this: dict[array[0]], dict[array[1]], etc...

Comment: @Phyber that is an excellent idea. I was trying to implement it got my dates into an array. But when I followed this code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168594/sort-objects-in-array-by-date all I am getting is [2018-01-19 08:00:00 +0000, 2018-01-13 08:00:00 +0000, 2017-12-22 08:00:00 +0000, 2018-01-02 08:00:00 +0000, ...]

Comment: @Phyber nvm I am an idiot i just used the sorted method on the array and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment - You can put all the keys from the dictionary into an array using dict.keys and sort the dates. Then simply access it using an index.

```
guard let dict = myJSON else{ return }

let arrayOfDateStrings = Array(dict.keys).sorted{$0 > $1}

print(dict[arrayOfDateString[indexPath.row]]) // If you want to access data inside tableView
```

If your date format was different you could use dateFormatter:

```
var arrayOfDates: [Date] = []

var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

for dateString in arrayOfDateStrings {
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
    if let date = date{
        arrayOfDates.append(date)
    }
}


arrayOfDates.sort(by: {$0.timeIntervalSince1970 > $1.timeIntervalSince1970})

var result: [String] = []

for date in arrayOfDates{
    result.append(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
}

print(dict[result[indexPath.row]]) // If you want to access data inside tableView
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [sort func](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2298238-sorted) here

```
let sortedKeys = dict.sorted(by: <)
```

**Code Work**

```
let dict = [
    "2017-12-21": 15561.05,
"2017-12-22": 13857.145,
"2017-12-23": 14548.71,
"2017-12-24": 13975.4363,
"2017-12-25": 13917.0275,
"2017-12-26": 15745.2575,
"2017-12-27": 15378.285,
"2017-12-28": 14428.76,
"2017-12-29": 14427.87,
"2017-12-30": 12629.8138,
"2017-12-31": 13860.1363,
"2018-01-01": 13412.44
  ]

print("-----before sort--------")
for item in dict{
    print(item)
}

let sortedKeys = dict.sorted(by: <) 

print("\n -----After sort--------")
for item in sortedKeys{
    print(item)
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response. I've just tried this but swift gasve me the error "Ambiguous reference to member '<' "

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Alamofire, but independent from that the best way is to convert the dictionary to an array of a custom struct.

This is an example in Swift 4 using `Codable`

```
let jsonString = """
{"bpi":{"2017-12-21":15561.05,"2017-12-22":13857.145,"2017-12-23":14548.71,"2017-12-24":13975.4363,"2017-12-25":13917.0275,"2017-12-26":15745.2575,"2017-12-27":15378.285,"2017-12-28":14428.76,"2017-12-29":14427.87,"2017-12-30":12629.8138,"2017-12-31":13860.1363,"2018-01-01":13412.44,"2018-01-02":14740.7563,"2018-01-03":15134.6513,"2018-01-04":15155.2263,"2018-01-05":16937.1738,"2018-01-06":17135.8363,"2018-01-07":16178.495,"2018-01-08":14970.3575,"2018-01-09":14439.4738,"2018-01-10":14890.7225,"2018-01-11":13287.26,"2018-01-12":13812.715,"2018-01-13":14188.785,"2018-01-14":13619.0288,"2018-01-15":13585.9013,"2018-01-16":11348.02,"2018-01-17":11141.2488,"2018-01-18":11250.6475,"2018-01-19":11514.925,"2018-01-20":12759.6413},"disclaimer":"This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index. BPI value data returned as USD.","time":{"updated":"Jan 21, 2018 00:03:00 UTC","updatedISO":"2018-01-21T00:03:00+00:00"}}
"""
```

---

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    var data = [Historical]()

    let dateFormatter : DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return formatter
    }()

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case bpi }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let bpi = try container.decode([String:Double].self, forKey: .bpi)
        for (key, value) in bpi {
            data.append(Historical(date: dateFormatter.date(from: key)!, value: value)))
        }
    }
}

struct Historical {
    let date : Date
    let value : Double
}
```

---

```
do {
    let data : Data(jsonString.utf8)
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print("error: ", error)
}
```

Now you can easily sort the `Historical` array.

```
print(result.data.sorted{ $0.date < $1.date })
```